# Streamed File Contains Strange Characters - An Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, encoding, utf-8

I have a WCF service end-point which generates an excel file and returns this file as a `MemoryStream` in the end in order to make client download the relevant file.

The file generated on the respective directory has no issues. I don't see any strange characters when I open and check it.

But, the file I returned with `MemoryStream` is full of strange unreadable characters.

[image]

My end-point is like that,

```
    public Stream GetEngagementFeedFinalizeData(int workspaceId, string startDate, string endDate, Stream data)
    {
        try
        {

            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;";
            string extension = "xls";
            string fileName = "report-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            string contentDisposition = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "attachment; filename={0}.{1}", fileName, extension);
            
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = contentType;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Set("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);

            //Here is some business logic and fetching data from db. Not any encoding
            //related issue. The data set is assigned to a variable
            //named "feedFinalizeDataTable" in the end

            feedFinalizeDataTable.TableName = "Summary";

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Tables.Add(feedFinalizeDataTable);

            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);
                    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                }

                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                var filePath = path + "\\" + "New.xls";
                excelPackage.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)); //This file is flawless

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                int length = (int)fs.Length;

                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = length;

                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

                int sum = 0;
                int count;

                while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                {
                    sum += count;
                }

                fs.Close();

                return new MemoryStream(buffer); //This file is full of unreadable chars as per above shared screenshot
            }
```

I'm using `OfficeOpenXml` to generate excel files.

Then, I checked both files encoding by open them with notepad. I saw that the file on the directory (the flawless one) has ANSI encoding. And, the one which is returned by the end-point (the broken one) has UTF-8 encoding.

After that, I try to change the encoding type of the stream like this,

```
var byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string fileStr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray), true).ReadToEnd();
var encd = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); //On the other topics I saw that ANSI represented with 1252
var end = encd.GetBytes(fileStr);
return new MemoryStream(end);
```

But, this doesn't help too. Though some of the strange characters are replaced with some other strange characters, but as I said, streamed file is still unreadable. And, when I open it with notepad to see its encoding, I saw that its still `UTF-8`.

Thus, I'm kind of stuck. I have also try directly to stream the generated excel file (without writing it to a directory and then reading it) with OfficeOpenXml's built in function called `.GetAsByteArray()`, but the downloaded file looks exactly the same as per above screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not return the `FileStream fs` instead of wrapping it in a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Clientside throws an error if I return `FileStream` instead `MemoryStream`

Comment: The starting characters PK indicate this is a binary zip file and not a text file. That’s consistent with an .XLSX Excel file.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes, this is also supposed to be an Excel file. But.. Any idea on whats wrong with the out stream?